# How to print variable name in a list

Tags: python, list

So i just want to print the variable's name. you can see from the case below

```
Andi = 100
Bill = 50
Kira = 90
List1 = [Andi, Bill, Kira]
for i in List1:
    print(i) # Here the problem, i want the Variable Name and Value printed together
```

## How to return it together? I respect all answer. Thank You :)

So guys i got this code from user, name "Anna Nevison". i wanted to accept her answer, but she delete her post so i post her code here :)

```
Andi = 100
Bill = 50
Kira = 90
List1 = ['Andi', 'Bill', 'Kira']
for i in List1:
    print(i, eval(i))
```

Comment: lists wont know the variable name. maybe you could use a tuple?

Comment: something like this: `Andi = ("Andi", 100)`

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? Thank you

Comment: To print both the name and value nicely, you could do `print(i[0] + ":" + str(i[1]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with plain variables.  Use a dictionary instead:

```
mydict = {
    'Andi': 100,
    'Bill': 50,
    'Kira': 25
}

for name in mydict:
    print(name, mydict[name])
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should consider using something like a dictionary instead?

```
people = {
    "Andi": 100,
    "Bill": 50,
    "Kira": 90
}
```

Then you can access the values associated with the dictionary's key like so:

```
print(people["Andi"]) # returns 100
```

Or you can iterate through the dictionary and print all of the values like so:

```
for person, number in people.items():
    print(f'{person}: {number}')
```

Of course the name 'person' for the variable could be something else... I just didn't know what the numbers in your example are.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these code could help:

```
Dict_var = dict({"Andi" : 100, 'Bill' : 50, "Kira" : 90})
for i,j in Dict_var.items():
    print(i,":",j)
```

For multiple keys and values:

```
keys = ['Andi', 'Bill', 'Kira']
values = [100, 50, 90]
Dict_var = dict(zip(keys,values))  
for i,j in Dict_var.items():
    print(i,":",j)
```

And the result could be like this:

```
Andi : 100
Bill : 50
Kira : 90
```