# Python printing variable name that is inside of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I was wondering how I would print the variable names inside of my list. Thanks

```
traits = [Character, Eye, Hair, Mouth, Shirt]
attributes.append({'trait_type': f"{traits=}", 'value': (os.path.basename(traits[a]))[:-4]})
```

What I want the output to be is:

```
'trait_type': 'Character'
```

I was searching and alot of threads said to make a dictionary, but wasn't sure if there was a way to brute force it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Replace the code to be the following

```py
mydict = {
    'var1-name': 'var1-value',
    'var2-name': 'var2-value',
    'var3-name': 'var3-value'
}

for name in mydict:
    print(name, mydict[name])
```

---

### Why ?

To be honest, because you cannot print an variable name inside a list,

you can check here --> [How to print variable name in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57455005/15564447)

---

### Solution

We need to change the list to become a dictionary to be able to print variable name in Python.

Answer (score 0):

#### one way of doing this:

```
first = 'green'
second = 'yellow'
third = 'orange'
mycolors = ['first','second','third']
for each in mycolors:
    print(each, vars()[each])
```

---

#### Output

```
first green
second yellow
third orange
```